# Can't install python-setuptools with yum on Ubuntu. Missing repolist

Tags: ubuntu, python, yum, repository

I can't install python-setuptool with yum on Ubuntu using the following command:

```
sudo yum install python-setuptools
```

I get this message

```
Setting up Install Process
No package python-setuptool available.
```

So I checked my repolist

```
sudo yum repolist
```

that returned

```
repolist: 0
```

**Which repository should I add, Or what else could I be missing?**

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `aptitude` in Ubuntu:

`sudo apt-get install python-setuptools`

Comment: Thanks @Raystafarian. What about adding repolist to yum ? I'm still interested in learning how to do it.